# Strange behavior of C++ array size

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I am writing a c++ function to calculate the size of an C-type array in C++

I noticed a very strange behavior when using these two different codes:

**code 1:**

```
int sz = sizeof array / sizeof *array;
```

**code 2:**

```
int array_size(const int *pointer)
 {   int count=0;
    if(pointer)
        while(*pointer) {
            count++;
            pointer++;
        }
    return count;

 }
```

When I applied these two method on a array, it gave me very strange behavior:

**example 1 :**

```
int array[10] = {31,24,65,32,14,5};// defined to be size 10 but init with size 6
```

the code one will give me size = 10, but code 2 will give me size 6,and when I print out the element that is pointed by *pointer, it will give me the correct array elements:

```
31 24 65 32 14 5
```

**example 2**

```
int array[] = {31,24,65,32,14,5}; // no declared size but init with 6
```

Code 1 will give me size 6, code 2 will give me size 12, and when I print out the element that is pointed by *pointer in code 2, it gives me :

```
31 24 65 32 14 5 -802013403 -150942493 1461458784 32767 -1918962231 32767
```

which is really not right, so what could be the problem that cause this behavior? and what are those numbers?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: @juanchopanza a failed emphasis :-P ...

Comment: And why you suppose that the second method will ever work?

Comment: "C - type array" doesn't make much sense to me. That's like saying "a C - style `if`".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This array has 10 elements, regardless of how you initialize it:

```
int array[10] = {31,24,65,32,14,5};
```

But the initialization sets the first 6 elements to certain values, and the rest to `0`. It is equivalent to this:

```
int array[10] = {31,24,65,32,14,5,0,0,0,0};
```

The first calculation using `sizeof` uses the actual size fo the array (its length times the size of an `int`), while the second one counts elements until it finds a `0`. So it doesn't calculate the length of the array, but the length of the first non-zero sequence in the array.

Note that the second method only "works" if the array has an element with value `0`. Otherwise you go out of bounds and invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks very much, So does that mean when the array size is not defined,  a pointer that points to the array will eventually go out of bound  and will give me strange value ?

Comment: @Chrim The array size is defined. Its length is 10. But a pointer is a pointer. You can't get the length of an array from a pointer to an element of the array (i.e. if an `int*` points to an element of an `int[42]`, there's no way you can get the `42` from the pointer.)

Answer (score 2):

`array_size` assumes that there is a `0` just past the end of the array. That assumption is unjustified.

Answer (score 1):

code 2 is not right. you can't assume an array end with 0